# Pandas: Function not executing as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df:

             score_difference   DNB selection selection_match
0                    1.040000  0.65       DNB        No Match
1                    0.894543  0.65       DNB        No Match
2                    2.120546  2.11       DNB        No Match
3                    0.672945  0.65       DNB        No Match
4                    1.578659  0.96       DNB        No Match
5                    2.746971  2.72       DNB        No Match
```

I am trying to write a function if `selection_match == 'No Match'` then `DNB = score_difference + 0.02`

```
def selection_mod_dnb(row):
    if row["selection_match"] == "No Match" and row['selection'] == "DNB":
        return 0.02 + float(row['score_difference'])
    else:
        return row['DNB']

df['DNB'] = df.apply(selection_mod_dnb, axis=1)
```

However, I return the same df without any modifications

```
df:

             score_difference   DNB selection selection_match
0                    1.040000  0.65       DNB        No Match
1                    0.894543  0.65       DNB        No Match
2                    2.120546  2.11       DNB        No Match
3                    0.672945  0.65       DNB        No Match
4                    1.578659  0.96       DNB        No Match
5                    2.746971  2.72       DNB        No Match
```

while it should return

```
             score_difference       DNB selection selection_match
0                    1.040000  1.060000       DNB        No Match
1                    0.894543  0.914543       DNB        No Match
2                    2.120546  2.140546       DNB        No Match
3                    0.672945  0.692945       DNB        No Match
4                    1.578659  1.598659       DNB        No Match
5                    2.746971  2.766971       DNB        No Match
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Comment: it seems that you don't have a `predicted_score_difference` column in your dataframe

Comment: Corrected the question

Comment: It works fine with me.

Comment: It does not at my end. For some reason I cannot seem to understand

Comment: Is there any better/other way to rewrite this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using apply when doing row based calculations:

`df['DNB'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.score_difference + 0.02 if x.selection_match == "No Match" else x.DNB, axis=1)`